# Converting jquery based component to angular 2/4 component?

Tags: jquery, angular

I'm in the process of learning angular and im making a test application for that.
I found a very nice "user card" design based on jquery and google material color pallete and i'd like to migrate it and create a component from it.

The cards can be found here- https://github.com/marlenesco/material-cards

I was wondering - what is the cleaest process of doing so? What should i include and where? Where should i add the javascript associated with that project

Comment: AngularJS or Angular2/4/5?

Comment: Angular 2/4, ill update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like jQuery is doing an awful lot in the codepen, so you can probably forget it altogether. Rather than using jQuery selectors, you could probably get away with using `@ViewChild` and `ElementRef` in order to get the DOM elements for manipulation.

My first step would be to make a Card component, so all your JS (TS?) is relative to just one instance.

In parts of the JS where classes are being added and removed, you could use `[ngClass]` directly in the template, and base their conditions on values you set in your component TS.

Lastly, instances such as:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    icon
      .removeClass('fa-arrow-left')
      .removeClass('fa-spin-fast')
      .addClass('fa-bars');

  }, 800);
```

Can be handled with `Observable.timer(800).subscribe(() => { // do stuff... (like update your ngClass conditions) }`.

Of course, there are many different approaches to convert this, but that would be a decent start.

I haven't got time just now, but if you're still stuck this evening, I may have time to have a go at a clean conversion solution.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Can i use the less files as is or any kind of conversations are needed aswell? Also general questions - if i want to include for example, google's css sheet like he did there, whats the best option for that?

Comment: hi jfly, i have issues with materializr, i've edited the post

Comment: I'm not 100% on the issue with materializr, but can have a better look later on. In the meantime, it may be worth just using the already compiled css to get you going with the conversion. You can always switch it back to less after you have it working ok. For ref, compiled css should be here: https://github.com/marlenesco/material-cards/tree/master/dist

Comment: Missed it, i took it and i see some progress - still having troubles with the heights and the widths - when i used it as a component - the height was not good, when i used the same div in the parent container - the height and width worked out fine

Comment: Thanks, i solved all my issues - i understand now that migrating is required :) thanks for your help